# With chrome Manifest v3 how can I add custom fields to request headers

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm migrating my chrome extension from manifest v2 to v3. As i read through google docs it says we should stop using blocking version of the Web Request API and should start using Declarative Net Request API.

In manifest version v2,

I was blocking the request headers and appending custom fields to it as below,

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
function(info) 
{
    if(info.type == "main_frame")
    {
        info.requestHeaders.push(
        {
            "name":"My Field Name",
            "value": info.url
        }
        );
        topURL[info.tabId] = info.url;
    }
    return {requestHeaders: info.requestHeaders};
}
{
urls: [
  "http://*/*"
]
},
["blocking","requestHeaders"]);
```

As given in declarativeNetRequest documentation I tried the below rules but it does nt work,(tried set and append).
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/
rules.json

```
[
{
    "id": 13,
    "priority": 1,
   "action": {
      "type": "modifyHeaders", 
      "requestHeaders": [{"header": "My Field Name", "operation": "set", "value": "top"}]
   }, 
   "condition": {
      "urlFilter": "http://*/*",
      "resourceTypes": ["main_frame", "xmlhttprequest"]
   }
}
]
```

1. My previous code was injecting dynamic data like url to "My Field Name". How to do it with declarativeNetRequest approach?
2. The above static rule too did nt work for modifyheaders but I can block the website loading when type changed to block.

Comment: There's no solution.

Answer (score 0):

With the current draft of Manifest V3, I'm afraid you can't port that code.

Depending on the concrete example, maybe you can use a workaround: for instance, if the requests on a website that you want to add the headers originate from JavaScript that runs after the page is loaded, you can inject code using [chrome.scripting.executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#method-executeScript) or contents script to patch the API (`fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest`) and then you can add the header there. That technique is also called "monkey patching" and comes with a couple of drawbacks. Also, be aware that scripts execute in their [isolated world](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#isolated_world), but you can still patch the API of a page.

That workaround is not a general solution and you will also not be able to change protected headers like `Cookie` (but it should work for custom headers). If you need to modify the initial request that loads a page, then I don't know of a way with the current draft. I think it is impossible in Manifest V3.